# How to get sum of two points that are tuple?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there anyway to sum two points not using "class point"

Input

```
a= (2,5)
b= (3,4)
c= a +b
```

Output

```
(5 , 9)
```

Comment: Assuming that you want to add the corresponding indices of each tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a comprehension plus `zip`:

```
c = tuple(a_n + b_n for a_n, b_n in zip(a, b))
```

This is obviously cumbersome if you need to do it a lot (not to mention slightly inefficient).  If you are going to be doing this sort of computation a lot, then you're better off using a library like numpy which allows arrays to be added as first-class objects.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 5])
b = np.array([3, 4])
c = a + b
```

If you go the numpy route, converting to and from numpy arrays is a bit expensive so I'd recommend that you store your points as arrays rather than tuple.

Comment: Only nitpick I could find is that `x` and `y` are a bit misleading in this context. They are not the `x` and `y` coordinates of the points, but rather the x-coordinates of `a` and `b` and then the y-coordinates.

Comment: @MadPhysicist -- Yeah ... I'm not sure what to call them.  If you have a proposal, I'm happy to update it (or you can go ahead and edit the name if you have something you think is better).  I could go with `x1` and `x2`, but that has the same problem as `x` and `y` if you are working with vectors in a non-cartesian plane... `coord_vec_1` and `coord_vec_2` would work but be super verbose.  I suppose we could do `c = tuple(sum(pair) for pair in zip(a, b))` -- But that only really works for sums and not differences ...

Comment: I don't think you need to change anything really. It just took me a few seconds to realize that I was reading the sum along the wrong axis, so I made a note of it for future generations :)

Comment: Perhaps `a_n`, `b_n`?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a functional approach:

```
t = tuple(map(sum, zip(a, b)))
```

Comment: The neat thing about this solution is that if you want to add _3 or more_ iterables instead of 2, it's as simple as adding it to the `zip` invocation:  `tuple(map(sum, zip(a, b, c, ...)))`.  The downside is that on python2.x you're creating 2 intermediate lists :-/.  python3.x doesn't have that problem though ...

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy
a = (2,5)
b = (3,4)
c = tuple(numpy.asarray(a) + numpy.asarray(b)) #Tuple convert is just because this is how your output defined. you can skip it...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the context is, but this is *one* of any other possible solutions....

Answer (score 1):

Complex numbers are (2-)tuples in disguise:

```
>>> a = 2+5j
>>> b = 3+4j
>>> c = a + b
>>> c
(5+9j)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I would recommend this ... It _only_ works for 2-tuples (which you've noted in your answer) and it only works for _some_ mathematical operations.  Specifically, if you want element-wise multiplication, then you're in a bit of a weird state -- addition works element-wise, but multiplication doesn't.

Comment: It works for the operations that make sense for a two-dimensional point.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]), zip(a, b))
```

Comment: Do you really think that OP should prefer this over the other solutions presented here?  Ideally, if you're going to post a solution that is this far off the beaten path, you should at least point out _why_ someone might want to use this rather than what was already posted.  Otherwise, we run the risk of having to _read_ code like this because someone who didn't know better just copy/pasted the first answer they saw on StackOverflow ...

Comment: @mgilson Hmm fair enough.